# Deploying a site with zero-knowledge?

Tags: privacy, tor, devops

Any methodologies of secret or private dev-ops as a service?
The use-case I was thinking of is for example, a productized service like on Fiverr, eg. Seller will deploy your site onto TOR network and guarantee that you retain privacy in that they never know the content of the site.